# problem with reset command and take photo command

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

The following is my code when the camera is activated:

```
Serial.println("File Created");
}
//camera operation
Serial.println("Sending Reset command");
SendResetCmd();
Serial.println("Sending Take Photo Command in 3 seconds");
delay(3000);
SendTakePhotoCmd();
// Get Image Size **************************************
Serial.println("Sending Read Image Size command");
delay(80);
GetImageSize();
delay(80);
Serial.print("Image Size: ");


void dumpCameraInput(boolean verbose)
{
    // Use this before issuing a command to be sure the buffer is empty.
    byte incomingbyte;
    if (verbose == true)
        Serial.print("clear camera buffer, dumping...");
    while(mySerial.available() > 0)
    {
        incomingbyte=mySerial.read();
        if (verbose == true)
            Serial.write(incomingbyte);
    }
    if (verbose == true)
        Serial.println("... END DUMPING");
}

void SendResetCmd()
{
    dumpCameraInput(true); //clear camera buffer
    mySerial.write(0x56);
    mySerial.write((byte)0);
    mySerial.write(0x26);
    mySerial.write((byte)0);
}

void SendTakePhotoCmd()
{
    dumpCameraInput(true); //clear camera buffer
    mySerial.write(0x56);
    mySerial.write((byte)0);
    mySerial.write(0x36);
    mySerial.write(0x01);
    mySerial.write((byte)0);
}
```

The results are as follows:

```
"File Created
Sending Reset command
clear camera buffer, dumping...v1... END DUMPING
Sending Take Photo Command in 3 seconds
clear camera buffer, dumping...v&VC0703 1.00
Ctrl infr exist
User-defined sensor
625
In... END DUMPING"
```

I don't need the "v1" and the words in between "dumping..." and "...END DUMPING".

What went wrong with my code? Is the problem coming from the void `dumpCameraInput(boolean verbose)` function?

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy-paste the text, as text, please. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The code section **while(mySerial.available() > 0) { ... }** is writing the text you say you don't want.  Doesn't sound like you wrote this code....

Comment: @RamblinRose alright thanks I'll work it out on that function... I was passed this project without any explanation on the code, and have to follow up with it. Thanks for understanding.